# How to use pysam.view to emulate all functions of samtools view

Tags: samtools, pysam

I am trying to use pysam.view() to filter out certain alignments from a BAM file. The problem I am facing is how to include several regions in the filter.

pysam.view() emulates the samtools view command which allows one to enter several regions separated by the space character, eg:

```
samtools view opts bamfile chr1:2010000-20200000 chr2:2010000-20200000
```

But the corresponding pysam.view call:

```
pysam.view(ops, bamfile, '1:2010000-20200000 2:2010000-20200000')
```

does not work. It does not return any alignments. I'm quite sure the problem lies in how to specify the list of regions, since the following command works fine:

```
pysam.view(ops, bamfile, '1:2010000-20200000')
```

and returns alignments.

My question is: does pysam.view support multiple regions and how does one specify this list? I have searched for documentation regarding this but not found anything.

Comment: I should add that I have tried the most obvious ways of specifying the list: using comma, semicolon, period, tab as delimiter and placing the regions in a list and a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

> The short answer to your question is that the format you'd use is
>
> `pysam.view(ops, bamfile, '1:2010000-20200000','2:2010000-20200000')`

*(Also note that the number indicating the end of each of your regions is ~10x larger than the beginning - it seems you might have intended `2010000-2020000` instead.)*

I have tested it using the following code:

```py
import pysam

my_bam_file = '/path/to/my/bam_file.bam'
alignments1 = pysam.view(my_bam_file, '1:2010000-4000000')
alignments2 = pysam.view(my_bam_file, '1:5000000-6000000')
alignments3 = pysam.view(my_bam_file, '1:2010000-4000000', '1:5000000-6000000')

print(len(alignments1) + len(alignments2) == len(alignments3))

[Output:] True
```

However, this way of extracting alignments is not very efficient, as the output you get is one large `str`, instead of individual alignments. To get a `list` of separate alignments instead, use the following code:

```py
import pysam

my_bam_file = '/path/to/my/bam_file.bam'
imported = pysam.AlignmentFile(my_bam_file, mode = 'rb')
regions = ('1:2010000-20200000','2:2010000-20200000')
alignments = []
for region in regions:
    bam = imported.fetch(region = region, until_eof = True)
    alignments.extend([alignment for alignment in bam])
```

Each element of `alignment` then ends up being a `pysam.AlignedSegment` object, with which you can work further using the functions in [pysam API](https://pysam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html).